# Beginner here. Code isn't obeying. I think the problem has something to do with accessing a variable that's within a class?

Tags: javascript

So I'm learning about how to use classes and I've made this code (it's exactly 100 lines long!) using P5.JS which is just supposed to draw three rectangles and three circles. One of the circles is able to be moved with the arrow keys, and the other two follow that one around. Here's the part that doesn't work: when the follower circles move over the squares, it's supposed to make them slow down as they move over it. I've tried everything.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
  noStroke();
  character1 = new character(250, 200, 30, 4);
  follower1 = new enemy(100, 20, 30, 2);
  follower2 = new enemy(200, 20, 30, 2);
  obstacle1 = new obstacle(200, 200, 100, 50, follower1.x, follower1.y, follower1.s);
  obstacle2 = new obstacle(300, 300, 50, 25, follower1.x, follower1.y, follower1.s);
  obstacle3 = new obstacle(200, 400, 25, 50, follower1.x, follower1.y, follower1.s);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  character1.drawCharacter();
  follower1.drawEnemy();
  follower2.drawEnemy();
  obstacle2.drawObstacle();
  obstacle1.drawObstacle();
  obstacle3.drawObstacle();
}

class character {
  constructor(x, y, d, s) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.d = d;
    this.s = s;
  }
  drawCharacter() {
    fill(255);
    ellipse(character1.x, character1.y, character1.d);
    if (keyIsDown(UP_ARROW)) {
      character1.y -= character1.s;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(DOWN_ARROW)) {
      character1.y += character1.s;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(LEFT_ARROW)) {
      character1.x -= character1.s;
    }
    if (keyIsDown(RIGHT_ARROW)) {
      character1.x += character1.s;
    }
  }
}

class enemy {
  constructor(x, y, d, s) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.d = d;
    this.s = s;
  }

  drawEnemy() {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.d);
    if (this.x < character1.x - this.d) {
      this.x += this.s;
    }
    if (this.x > character1.x + this.d) {
      this.x -= this.s;
    }
    if (this.y < character1.y - this.d) {
      this.y += this.s;
    }
    if (this.y > character1.y + this.d) {
      this.y -= this.s;
    }
  }
}

class obstacle {
  constructor(x, y, w, h, enemyX, enemyY, enemyS) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.w = w;
    this.h = h;
    enemyX = enemyX;
    enemyY = enemyY;
    enemyS = enemyS;
  }
  drawObstacle(enemyX, enemyY, enemyS) {
    fill(255);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    rect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
    if (
      this.x - this.w / 2 - 10 < enemyX &&
      this.x + this.w / 2 + 10 > enemyX &&
      this.y - this.h / 2 - 10 < enemyY &&
      this.y + this.h / 2 + 10 > enemyY
    ) {
      enemyS = 0.5;
    } else {
      enemyS = 2.5;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try only having one obstacle. Here's my guess:

draw calls `obstacle.drawObstacle` three times, and if an enemy should be slowed down by `obstacle1` or `obstacle2`, it doesn't matter because `enemy.s` will be reset by `obstacle3.drawObstacle`

I highly recommend that each of your character and enemy class have a `draw` and a `move` method, and put everything about how enemies move within the enemy class. Maybe the obstacle class should have a `draw` and maybe a `isCollidingWith` method that `enemy.move` would call.

Keeping all your logic for an class within the class means that you can do variants much more easily. For example, maybe later you'll want to have an enemy that's much slower but isn't hindered by obstacles at all. Having all the logic within the class makes that easy. Putting the logic within the obstacle class would quickly become a nightmare if you have enough different types of enemies.

Also, you could have a `game` object that holds everything about the game including `character`, `enemies`, and `obstacles` properties and  `draw` and `move` methods that call the respective methods on character, enemy, and obstacle objects, and a `destroy` or `quit` method that clears its properties and such. (In some languages this is important, because if you were to add a `game` property to each piece in the game, they'd have handles to each other and since (in some languages) garbage collection only reaps objects that have no references to them, they'll take up memory much longer than you want.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Trying different things for hours but it works a little bit better now. Honestly another big part of the problem was that there were a few times when I would refer to the x or y position of a whole class instead of just the instance.

Comment: Glad it helped! If this was the right answer, please mark it as the right answer.